# Como gerar um booleano (0|1) aleatóriamente dada a probabilidade do evento verdade em C?

Tags: c

Estou tentando criar uma função para um problema maior, e apenas a função possui a seguinte descrição:  ***devolve um inteiro nao nulo com probabilidade f, e devolve 0 com probabilidade 1 − f, onde 0 ≤ f ≤ 1***

Meu código está nesse ponto, mas acho que misturei conceitos e nem sei mais o que estou fazendo. Como corrigir?

```
int sorteia_voto_com_falha (double f);
    int i, N;

    srand(RAND_MAX);
    for(i = 1; i < N; i++)
       return(rand() % 1-f);
```

Na main() a pessoa insere o numero de votos N, e o enunciado diz basicamente que cada voto que uma pessoa recebe, tem probabilidade f de ser contabilizado com falha para o candidato oposto.

[Link do enunciado](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1xjTxzSX_YgATAKKJfpab5UrzdAjHap_d)

Comment: Sua explicação está bem confusa. No entanto se você verificar a precedência dos operadores constatará que ` return(rand() % 1-f);` é equivalente a ` return((rand() % 1) - f);`. É isto mesmo o que deseja? Afinal ` rand() % 1` sempre resultará em zero. Outro ponto importante é que, apesar de você ter codificado um loop `for` a função será encerrada no primeiro `return`.

Comment: @anonimo Muito obrigada pelo seu retorno. Eu incluí um link que mostra o enunciado do problema, talvez fique mais claro o que eu estou tentando fazer, do que eu explicar com minhas palavras. Por favor, considere uma leitura. Estou tentando desesperadamente aprender, ir aos poucos pra entender o geral, infelizmente nao tenho pra quem perguntar. Obrigada!

Answer (score 0):

A função `rand()` retorna um valor entre 0 e RAND_MAX.

Essa variável está definida no arquivo `stdlib.h`.

E eles são equiprováveis num intervalo:

```
_____________________________________
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |
-------------------------------------
0    ^      RAND_MAX/2           RAND_MAX
     |
     5% estão abaixo desse número
```

Sua função `HouveFalha(double probabilidade)` deve ser algo do tipo:

```
int HouveFalha(double probabilidade)
{
  return ( ( (double)rand() / (double)RAND_MAX ) < probabilidade ) ? 1 : 0;
}
```

Não esqueça de inicializar uma semente com `srand()`:

```
srand(time(NULL));
```

link do [IME](https://www.ime.usp.br/~pf/algoritmos/aulas/random.html)

#### Operador ternário

O operador `?` usado no código é um operador ternário, ele se chama ternário pois recebe três operandos.

Em linguagem funcional seria o equivalente:

?(condição, verdade, falso)

Em notação agébrica (o utilizado em linguagem de programação) é usado da seguinte maneira:

condição ? verdade : falso

essa linha é equivalente a:

if(condição)
{
  return verdade;
}
else
{
  return falso
}

De tanto escrever esse código alguém inventou esse atalho.

Nesse caso a `condição` é:

```
( ( (double)rand() / (double)RAND_MAX ) < probabilidade )
```

#### A semente do gerador de números aleatórios GNA (RNG)

O rand() gera números pseudo-aleatórios, isto é:

- Eles são gerados matematicamente com alguma conta
- A semente é usada na inicialização do algorítmo.
- São equiprováveis num intervalo.
- Dada a mesma semente, será gerada a mesma sequência.
- Não são adequados para criptografia/segurança.
- São úteis em simulações Monte Carlo corriqueiras.

Para se criar uma aleatoriedade na semente, usa-se a hora atual como semente, não é obrigatório, mas é uma prática comum:

```
srand(time(NULL));
```

Comment: Como está ficando extensa e fugindo do foco da resposta, a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107740/discussion-on-answer-by-edney-como-gerar-um-booleano-01-aleatoriamente-dada-a), que é mais adequado para interações deste tipo.Vocês podem prosseguir normalmente clicando no link fornecido.